# Field added to user profile does not appear in database?

Tags: 7, users

Drupal 7 provides the ability to add custom fields to the user profile through admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

I have added a *firstname* field. It appears on the registration page but in the database the field is not added. Where it is stored?

Answer (score 2):

The additional fields are stored in a separate table like field_data_field_first.

Answer (score 0):

When the field is added, a new table is created. In Drupal 6 fields might be added as columns to the main table, but in Drupal 7 that is never the case.

Comment: Sorry i have verified twice in userstable the field is not adding as fisrtname.iam using drupal7.do i need to code anything while form sumitting.i just added field using the above method and checked to show in registration page

Comment: can you say me the database table where these fields are added.iam searching in usertable but it is not added